# Why 2 static libs can't call to each other's function

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I have 2 static libs: liba.a, libb.a and a executable that link both.
liba.a is calling to function foo which is defined in libb.a
both libs compile successfully BUT my exe seems to have linker errors:

```
undefined reference to `foo'
```

need help...

using ubuntu 14.04.
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Comment: what platform? What compilers?

Comment: You need help with writing problem descriptions. You also don't seem to be able to spell "static"...?

Comment: How do you intend to run an EXE on Ubuntu, I wonder?

Comment: How are you compiling the executable? Are you making sure to link both libs?

Comment: You need to show the code that defines `foo`. There's not enough information here to answer your question.

Comment: by exe I mean my executable file. not .exe

Comment: @yehudahs: What prevented you from simply writing that out in full, so as to be unambiguous?

Comment: your question should look like this: this is liba (header and src with one line defining foo), this is libb (header and src with one line defining  a function (if any). And this is how I compile: 3 compile commands. This is the error I get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you build:

```
g++ liba.a libb.a myCode.o -o myExe
```

This is wrong, because [the order of the arguments matters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/560648). If `myCode` uses symbols from `liba` and `libb`, those libraries must be specified *after* it on the command line:

```
g++ myCode.o liba.a libb.a -o myExe
```

Alternatively, you can request that the linker treat all three as a "group"; if you do so, dependencies will be resolved for you within that group without needing to worry about order:

```
g++ "-Wl,--start-group" liba.a libb.a myCode.o "-Wl,--end-group" -o myExe
```

Comment: you are right !!! I always thought that the linker searches ALL the libs and .o file for function names. Didn't know that it searches only forwards... :( it's a pity that I had to spend some hours of my life to understand it.

Comment: @yehudahs: No, it's a pity you didn't read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24675715/560648)!